# How can I accept a ulong type variable in C#?

Tags: c#, ulong

How can we take input of a ulong type variable in C#? if we use Console.ReadLine() then how to convert string to ulong ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c# : string to ulong conversion keeping precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157521/c-sharp-string-to-ulong-conversion-keeping-precision)

Comment: @dibery that doesn't seem to be about parsing a string to a ulong, considering a ulong is an unsigned long integer and that question deals with fractional values.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [How to convert a string to a number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number)

`ulong res = ulong.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`

Comment: Sure, the link contains all the info regarding that...

Answer (score 0):

For number, boolean, and some other types, there are defined `TryParse` methods. These methods will take a `string`, and return a boolean (`true` if it was parsed successfully, `false` if it was unsuccessful) and the actual parsed value as an `out` parameter. It's strongly advisable to use these when dealing with user input or input that isn't guaranteed to be the type you're trying to parse.

This will avoid parse errors that would be thrown by `ulong.Parse(Console.ReadLine())` if the input data isn't right, etc.

For example:

```
if (ulong.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out ulong parsedValue))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"You entered {parsedValue}.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid value.");
}
```

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number) for more info.